# iText shrink table column to fit contents

Tags: java, itext

In my iText document, I have a lot of tables scattered around, each with only one row of two columns. I would like to automatically shrink the leftmost column to fit its contents, and expand the rightmost column to fill the remaining space.

The exact contents of these two columns varies greatly, so there's no way to determine ahead of time what the exact width should be.

All of the content in this screenshot is wrapped in one outer table. Each nested table has its two columns highlighted red and blue. I would like to shrink the red columns as narrow as they can get without forcing the text to take up more lines than it has to.
[image: nested table layout]

In this case, the contents of the red cells are just a paragraph each, but it's possible they may contain a further-nested table with two cells of its own (which probably faces the same problem).

Is there a simple way to expand one column and shrink another without specifying exact or relative widths?

Comment: Since you're using the itext tag, I presume you're using some version of iText5? And if that's the case, I'm guessing everything's wrapped in a table because you wanted the borders? Honestly, I'd suggest just switching to iText7 if it's possible and drop the tables alltogether. In iText7 you can set borders on any block-like element, and get the width to be width of contents as well. In iText5, I don't even want to start thinking about how to do it.

Comment: What would be the equivalent element to use to place two blocks next to each other like this in iText 7?

Comment: I'll see what it takes to reproduce the above layout in java and post it as an answer here, comments are a bit too limited for code discussion/examples

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iText7 (and ditching the table for layout altogether), you can achieve this look and layout by building on the following example:

Output looks like this:
[image]

Code used to generate output above:

```
 public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

    Text t = new Text("Date:").setBold();
    p.add(t);
    t= new Text("10/12/17").setUnderline();
    p.add(t);
    p.add(new Tab());
    p.add(createTwoPartBorderedText("Catalog Year:   ","2017"));
    p.add(new Tab());
    p.add(createTwoPartBorderedText("L Number","2019284"));

    doc.add(p);

    doc.close();
}

public Paragraph createTwoPartBorderedText(String contentOne, String contentTwo){
    Paragraph container= new Paragraph();

    Text one = new Text(contentOne).setBold();
    Border solidRed = new SolidBorder(Color.RED,1f);
    one.setBorder(solidRed);
    container.add(one);

    Text two  =new Text(contentTwo);
    two.setUnderline();
    Border solidBlue = new SolidBorder(Color.BLUE,1f);
    two.setBorder(solidBlue);
    container.add(two);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm guessing it will probably be a lot of effort to update from iText 5 to 7, so I won't be able to work on this right now, but thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Porting effort depends on the extent of your code-base, certain things are easy enough to port (html to pdf conversion), other things are easier in iText7 (see above), and some things can require a large effort because the API got changed and they involve a lot of operations(manually placed layout). Some things got removed and their functionality split over other classes (Good riddance, `ColumnText.go()`). You can have a look at the iText7 jumpstart tutorial to get a feel for 7 and decide how much the porting effort is yourself :)

Comment: I found out today that the reason we're using iText 5 is that's the last (?) free version we can use in our closed-source product without a license. Is there any way to achieve this look within the confines of iText 5? Or will we just have to live with it until such time as we decide to give in and buy a licence?

Comment: eeeeuuh, you might want to double-check if your project complies to the AGPL, which has conditions on making your source code available. There is no version of iText5 that isn't AGPL btw, and for the general description of your project (closed source), you'd need a commercial license.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing that out. We're now getting a license and preparing to upgrade to iText 7. I'll try your solution out once that's done.

Comment: It looks like your example will always put the prompts (bold) and the values (underlined) inline with each other. I would like to replicate the look of CSS' `display: inline-block`. Note how the "Middle Name" prompt in my original screenshot wraps in its own block while its corresponding value sits to the right of it. Is that possible without using tables?

Comment: The wrapping should be do-able by just setting the width of the element

Comment: So there's no way to set the widths automatically? I'd like to have the blocks get as wide as they need to be until they fill up their whole container (the cell in the outer table), and then only start wrapping the text inside when it gets too long to fit on one line.

Comment: There are ways to set width automatically, but that sounds like an awfully specific definition of automatic behaviour >.>. I'm also a bit confused about the reference to tables, since my example contains none and I specifically advised to ditch tables as a layout mechanism.

Comment: Well, I've been using tables in two ways - the inner tables that placed the prompts and values side-by-side, and the outer tables that the fields are all aligned in. These outer tables have to support colspan, rowspan, horizontal/vertical alignment, percent-based column widths, table headers, cell borders, etc. so I *must* use these.

The fields can also be placed outside of tables, directly into the document, but tables are still going to be an integral part of this.